# trying to use variable in bash-curl, getting curl: (3) <url> malformed

Tags: bash, curl

we get error on trying to use variable in curl url block, how i can fix it?
variable is
NEXUS_UPLOAD='http://mynexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ru/123/project/1.0/1.0.289/'

```
#!/bin/bash -v
    for i in $(cat upload.list); do
        content=$(curl -v -u "$NEXUS_USER":"$NEXUS_USER_PASSWORD" --upload-file "$i" "${NEXUS_UPLOAD}")
        echo $content
    done
```

error is:

> ```
> * <url> malformed
> * Closing connection -1
> curl: (3) <url> malformed
> ```

if we have direct link in this script, curl worked correctly

```
#!/bin/bash -v
    for i in $(cat upload.list); do
        content=$(curl -v -u "$NEXUS_USER":"$NEXUS_USER_PASSWORD" --upload-file "$i" http://mynexus.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ru/123/project/1.0/1.0.289/)
        echo $content
    done
```

using just `$NEXUS_UPLOAD` without quotes getting - curl: no `URL` specified!
also I try to use `"$NEXUS_UPLOAD"` in script, but still get malformed error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the curly brackets around NEXUS_UPLOAD and use -x to enable the trace option, and don't forget to "export" the variables.

You can see a list of exported variables with `declare -p`

```
#!/bin/bash -x
    for i in $(cat upload.list); do
        content=$(curl -v -u "$NEXUS_USER":"$NEXUS_USER_PASSWORD" --upload-file "$i" "$NEXUS_UPLOAD")
        echo $content
    done
```

Here's [a link](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/all-about-curly-braces-bash/) explaining when they are useful.

For example:

```
i=image.jpg

convert $i ${i%jpg}png
```

Comment: problem is still actual, same result
#!/bin/bash -v
    for i in $(cat upload.list); do
        content=$(curl -v -u "$NEXUS_USER":"$NEXUS_USER_PASSWORD" --upload-file "$i" "$NEXUS_UPLOAD")
        echo $content
    done
* <url> malformed
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) <url> malformed

* <url> malformed
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) <url> malformed

Comment: Try running it again with trace enabled. "set -x"

Comment: ++ cat upload.list
+ for i in '$(cat upload.list)'
++ curl -v -u : --upload-file change.log ''
* <url> malformed
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) <url> malformed
+ content=
+ echo

url is empty with debug

Comment: OK so the variables are all empty. $NEXUS_USER $NEXUS_USER_PASSWORD and $NEXUS_UPLOAD. Try "export NEXUS_USER NEXUS_USER_PASSWORD NEXUS_UPLOAD"

Comment: fixed, ill forget about export at script start, thank you!